# ASP.net C# image processing

Tags: c#, image-processing, sms-gateway, kiosk

I am designing a website for PUBLIC TRANSPORT TICKETING SYSTEM using ASP.NET c# and MSSQL..So when a customer registers in the site, I want to send SMS with a barcode to him to use that in the bus to validate him..

so in the bus there is KIOSK and also a barcode reader..When he get into the bus first he has to validate himself..

So i want to implement this : when the passenger shows the image of the barcode in his mobile the barcode should compare it with the database and if it's validated proceed if not give an error message..

plz consider my question and kind be enough to reply..
Thank alot..

Comment: Your question is way to vague. You need to tell us [what you have tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

Usually barcodes are compared as strings, not as images. Note that it's not recommended to store the barcode as image in the database. You simply can store the barcode value (string) in the database and compare it with the barcode recognition result.
We currently generate barcodes (Code 93) using a 3rd party toolkit named leadtools. This toolkit gives you the ability to read\write common barcodes. For more information, see the following link:
http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/to/leadtools.topics.barcode~ba.topics.programmingwithleadtoolsbarcode.html

Answer (score 1):

Barcodes are NOT generally implemented by image comparison.

Rather, the barcode evaluates to a string or number, which is then a PK into a backend database somewhere.

(Eg, check on any product in your kitchen pantry.  The barcode will often have a human-readable version of the number that the barcode represents, written below the barcode).

You've specified there's a barcode reader in place... This will do the "heavy lifting" of reading the barcode and passing the resultant string/number into the system.

Comment: So if you're asking how to "compare" a number passed into your system, with a record back in a database... you need to completely re-word your question and be specific about what specific areas of the system you need help with.  You can't ask "how can I implement this entire system" in one question ;-)

Comment: i want the customers to register in my site online.. and i am issuing a printed card like smart card with a barcode and initial credit points..I want to know whether when the credit limit goes down can I give feature to recharge the card online using VISA, AMERICAN Express and the other cards..

Comment: This question is unrelated to your original question.